# Scanning WiFi frequencies around the house

Tags: wireless-networking

Do you know how to find out which WiFi frequencies are in use around my neighbourhood? Aircrack-ng toolkit preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `airodump-ng` with channel hopping enabled, and  it will list all the networks it can find, including what channel they are on. Each channel has a specific frequency associated with it, which you can look up on the internet.

You might have to put the interface into monitor mode first with `airmon-ng start <interface>`

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan|grep Frequency
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you said Aircrack toolkit perfered, but I have found [inSSIDer](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider/) to be a lot easier to use. It has a really easy to use interface and visualization tools to help see what frequencies are crowded and what ones are open. Unforunatly I do not know of any good visualizers for Linux.

If you have your heart set on aircrack-ng (like if you are looking to play with cracking WEP encrypted passwords) I recommend using the [BackTrack](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/) LiveCD. They have a very active forum with a lot of tutorials that can walk you through the usage of the aircrack-ng suite.